# How to force an Apache Mahout application read directly from the HDFS

Tags: hdfs, mahout

I have implemented an Apache Mahout application (attached bellow) which does some basic computations. To do so it is required to load the dataset from my local machine. This application comes in the form of a jar file, but then its being executed within a hadoop pseudo-distributed cluster. The terminal command for that is: $ hadoop jar /home/eualin/ApacheMahout/tdunning-MiA-5b8956f/target/mia-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar mia.recommender.ch03.IREvaluatorBooleanPrefIntro2 "/home/eualin/Desktop/links-final"

Now, my question is how to do the same, but this time by reading the dataset from the HDFS (we, of course, suppose that the dataset is already stored in HDFS, e.g. in /user/eualin/output/links-final}. What should change in that case? This might help: hdfs://localhost:50010/user/eualin/output/links-final

```
package mia.recommender.ch03;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.TasteException;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.DataModelBuilder;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.IRStatistics;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderBuilder;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.eval.RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.common.FastByIDMap;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.eval.GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.GenericBooleanPrefDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.NearestNUserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.LogLikelihoodSimilarity;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.PreferenceArray;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.UserNeighborhood;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.Recommender;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.UserSimilarity;

import java.io.File;

public class IREvaluatorBooleanPrefIntro2 {
    private IREvaluatorBooleanPrefIntro2() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1)                 {
            System.out.println("give file's HDFS path");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        DataModel model = new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel(
                GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap(
                        new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel(new FileDataModel(new File(args[0])))));
        RecommenderIRStatsEvaluator evaluator =
                new GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator();
        RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) throws TasteException {
                UserSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);
                UserNeighborhood neighborhood =
                        new NearestNUserNeighborhood(10, similarity, model);
                return new GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
            }
        };
        DataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new DataModelBuilder() {
            @Override
            public DataModel buildDataModel(FastByIDMap<PreferenceArray> trainingData) {
                return new GenericBooleanPrefDataModel(
                        GenericBooleanPrefDataModel.toDataMap(trainingData));
            }
        };
        IRStatistics stats = evaluator.evaluate(
                recommenderBuilder, modelBuilder, model, null, 10,
                GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator.CHOOSE_THRESHOLD,
                1.0);
        System.out.println(stats.getPrecision());
        System.out.println(stats.getRecall());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, directly, since the non-distributed code has no knowledge of HDFS. Instead, copy the file to a local location in `setup()` and then read it from a local file.

Comment: Sean, thank you very much for your reply. Q1: what you mean by "setup()"? Q2: any quick way to transform this non-distributed code - found on your book - into a distributed one? In other words, how could I use your code within a distributed enviroment?

Comment: `setup()` in the `Mapper`. You will have to copy/modify the code for this. Distributing a computation is the very thing that makes for whole projects like Mahout. No there's no automatic way to do it. In fact I have moved on from Mahout to commercialize (distributed) real-time recommenders alone as a company. (Advertisement: http://myrrix.com) This pseudo-distribution is just a novelty, really.